# How to make settings (or options) in jQuery plugin available for all methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working with jQuery for a few months (I'm still a disciple of Mootools) and now I'm trying to create my first plugin in jQuery.

The thing is, I would like to have some methods in my plugin and I would like that those methods were able to access all the "properties" of the plugin.

For example:

```
(function( $ ) {
     $.fn.test= function(method) {
          var settings;
          init: function() {
               var _defaults = {
                    option1: 'value1',
                    option2: 'value2',
                    option3: 'value3',
                    url: 'default.php'
               };
               settings = $.extend({}, _defaults, method);
          },
          load: function(){
               $.ajax({
                    cache   : false,
                    type    : "GET",
                    url     : settings.url,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success : function(response){  
                         console.log(response);
                    },
                    error   : function(response) { 
                         alert("Error loading data."); 
                    }
               });              
          }
     }
}( jQuery ));
```

Now for the call of the plugin itself:
    // Initialise
    $('#box1').test({
         url: 'another-url.php'
    });

```
// Call the load method
$('#element').test('load');
```

The problem is, when I call "load" the settings.url is equals to 'default.php' instead of 'another-url.php'.

Is it possible to deal with this as in OOP, I mean, make 'settings' a property of the "class" and then all changes to that property are persistent?

What I would like to achieve in pseudo-code:

```
Class Test{
     // Specify default settings
     private settings = // some default values;

     // Constructor
     public Test(specificSettings){
          //Code to merge/update specificSettings with settings
     }
     public load(){
           // If I access this.settings in here, I will get the
           // updated settings and not the default one
     }

}
```

This also will allow me to have as many "instances" as needed, each one with its own settings values.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you tried what i given in answer ?

Comment: Hello @KevalBhatt! It worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: you know how to accept answer  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so as per your plugin structure you have to call first init method
because when you call $("....").test('load') so it will not call init function so it will take default url which is declared at first time

1. $("....").test('init')
2. $('#box1').test({ url: 'another-url.php' })
3. $("....").test('load')

Or internally in plugin always call init(); it will solve your problem

```
(function( $ ) {
     $.fn.test= function(method) {
          var settings;
          **init();** // call internally
          init: function() {
               var _defaults = {
                    option1: 'value1',
                    option2: 'value2',
                    option3: 'value3',
                    url: 'default.php'
               };
               settings = $.extend({}, _defaults, method);
          },......
```